# Sync. VideoView using Range Seekbar

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar

I am using [Range Seekbar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) in my project. Now I am playing a video in `VideoView` and want to sync. `VideoView` using Range Seekbar.

I have already implemented following code but problem is videoview is synced only when I `stop Dragging Seekbar`.

I want to sync. videoview **While** I am dragging the range seekbar. I know that it is implemented in normal seekbar via `onProgressChanged`; but I want to implement a similar thing for `Range seekbar`.

***Current Code***

```
RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 100, getBaseContext());
seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {                    
                current_pos=minValue*1000;
                videoView.seekTo(current_pos);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just add the below code before calling the `Listener`,

```
RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 100, getBaseContext());
seekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
```

This is by default `false`; making it `true` would solve the problem. :)